# Function which returns either the positive or negative elements of the list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a `splitList` function that takes an option as input and returns either positive or negative elements of the list.

So far this is all I have:

```
def splitList([1,-3,5,7,-9,-11,10,2,-4], option)
```

- In case "option" = 0 I'd like to get all the positive elements.
- In case "option" = 1 I'd like to get all the negative elements.

Comment: which language, python ?

Comment: yeah its in python, my bad. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you enter 0 in the place where option is, it will return  a list of all the positive elements

Comment: No, the question is "do you always want to exclude zero?"

Comment: what's wrong with using `for` loop? Have you tried it out with a for loop plus some if-else statements? I see that everyone is telling you to use list comprehension but if you are not familiar with basic `for` loop, then none of them will be a good answer.

Comment: Which university do you attend?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly DRYer alternative:

```
import operator

def split_list(iterator, positive=True):
    sign_test = operator.gt if positive else operator.lt
    return [i for i in iterator if sign_test(i, 0)]
```

If you want it to return nonpositive/nonnegative instead, you can replace `gt` & `lt` with `ge` and `le`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you use more meaningful words to describe your intent for positive or negative integers. Here's an example function for you:

```
def split_list(data_set, positive=True):
    if positive:
        return [i for i in data_set if i > 0]
    return [i for i in data_set if i < 0]

example = [1,-3,5,7,-9,-11,0,2,-4]
print split_list(example, True)
print split_list(example, False)
```

returns:

```
[1, 5, 7, 2]
[-3, -9, -11, -4]
```

As a side note, this example assumes 0 is considered neither positive nor negative--you can easily adjust the `>` or `<` to `>=` or `<=` to adjust your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative:

```
import operator

def split_list(iterator, positive=True, sign_test=(operator.lt, operator.gt)):
    return [i for i in iterator if sign_test[positive](i, 0)]
```

Call it like so:

```
>>> split_list([1, -2, 4, 0, -4], False)
[-2, -4]
```

or:

```
>>> split_list([1, -2, 4, -0, 4], True, (operator.lt, operator.ge))
[1, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
def split_list():
    pos = []
    neg = []

     for i in alist:
        if i < 0:
            pos.append(i)
     print pos
     for i in alist:
        if i > 0:
            neg.append(i)
     print neg



def main():
    alist = [54,26,-93,-17,-77,31,44,55,20]
    manipulate_data(alist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```